# Accessing php file from remote host

Tags: php, apache, docker

I've a host running with centos 7 minimal in which I have set up apache server running php inside docker. My apache-config.conf file looks like :-

```
<VirtualHost xxxx.xxxx.com:80>
  ServerAdmin root@xxxx.xxxx.com   
  DocumentRoot /var/www/dl
  <Directory “/var/www/site“>
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
  </Directory>
 ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error_log
 CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access_log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

if the host name of the remote centos 7 machine is xxxx.xxxx.com, how can I access the php content in my windows machine running firefox browser?

Thanks.

Comment: What is your question? It is unclear.

Comment: can we see your docker setup, to see if you shared the folder correctly from the host ?

Comment: So I just pulled in the php official image from  https://hub.docker.com/_/php/ and my docker file is done as it's shows under the section Create a Dockerfile in your PHP project.

Comment: the requirement is that I need to have a apache php running in a docker container in centos 7 minimal machine & able to access the php files from the same machine to my firefox browser running a different machine with windows environment, remotely given I have a ip address or hostname set for the centos machine.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `xxxx.xxxx.com` in your apache config to `localhost` and try to open in browser http://localhost.

Comment: I made it xxxx to hide the real domain in this forum & if I do localhost then it will not serve the purpose. Assume I'm using ip address which I'm able to ping from my windows environment. The host is a remote centos 7 environment system.